# Pulling CRM 2011 data into Sharepoint 2013 using a webpart?

Tags: sharepoint, web-parts, crm

I've been hunting all day trying to find some good examples/tutorials on how to pull data into Sharepoint 2013 from CRM 2011. The best thing I have found so far is a SP2010 example, but with VS2012 and SP2013 it seems like so much has changed, and trying to make that tutorial work isn't going well thus far.

I have no experience with SP; with CRM I have used the CrmSvcUtil.exe in the past to generate a class and use that within a .NET app in order to view/update data in CRM. I tried implementing this into my Visual Web Part, but I need to be able to add connection strings to the config file which it doesn't seem are recognized by the web part. I see that I can add a service reference to the CRM Organization service but I'm not sure if/how I can use that to query data. Any help is appreciated, or if anyone could point me in the direction of some good documentation. Thanks!

Answer (score 0):

You have got couple of options.

(1) Use SharePoint 2013 client API. 
Consume the client API from your CRM plugin / custom workflow to update the crm data to     SharePoint 2013.

(2) Consume  SharePoint 2013 webservices from CRM plugin / custom workflow.

I don't think this works in sandbox based solution.